# Limiting the text length in a cell in NSTableView column

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecolumn

I have a NSTableView with 2 columns. I do have code to enter text in the cells for each row.
Is there a way to limit the number of characters entry in the cell say max upto 10?

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell the cell self to cut the NSString. But you can cut the inputString

```
cell.textLabel.text = [yourString substringToIndex:10];
```